# How to redirect 403 errors with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

The first few lines of my .htaccess file are as follows.

```
ErrorDocument 400 https://www.rydercragie.com
ErrorDocument 401 https://www.rydercragie.com
ErrorDocument 403 https://www.rydercragie.com
ErrorDocument 404 https://www.rydercragie.com
ErrorDocument 500 https://www.rydercragie.com
```

They all work apart from https://RyderCragie.com/.htaccess. Any ideas why an error is still shown on that page and how to fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Requests for `.htaccess` are quite likely blocked by directives in the server config - before the `ErrorDocument` in `.htaccess` is processed.

In order to catch this, you would need to define the `ErrorDocument` earlier in the main server config, not `.htaccess`. The same applies to other requests that are blocked early by Apache, such as requests that contain encoded slashes in the URL-path, and most 500 errors.

Although any request for `.htaccess` in the wild is unquestionably malicious, so a minimal (default) server response is probably the best response.

However, implementing all your `ErrorDocument` directives as *external* redirects to the document root is generally a bad idea (you lose details of the request that triggered the response, bad experience for users, etc.)

Give your user a meaningful error response, without the redirect. Error documents should be served via an internal subrequest. For example:

```
ErrorDocument 403 /error-documents/e403.html
```

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#errordocument